# Implementing headphone transfer function (HPTF)

Tags: impulse-response, transfer-function

This document on HRTFs, [A Spherical Far Field HRIR/HRTF Compilation, of the Neumann KU 100](http://www.audiogroup.web.fh-koeln.de/FILES/AIA-DAGA2013_HRIRs.pdf), talks about headphone compensation filters.

Searching Google returns http://www.ak.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/a0135/Publikationen/2010/Brinkmann_2010_On_the_effect_of_individual_headphone_compensation_in_binaural_synthesis.pdf

These are technical documents, and I am not an expert in the field, I have no training in signals processing, so it is difficult for me to see what is being said.

Does this mean that I could improve my HRIRs by getting hold of a HPTF filter suited for my headphones, and convolving them with it?

Is there any chance such a transfer function might be available for these particular headphones ([Apple EarPods](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MD827ZM/A/apple-earpods-with-remote-and-mic))

π

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you mean by "improve my HRIRs?"

Comment: @nispio, I am trying to create 12 HRIRs that I perceive as being very distinct from one another.  So I'm trying to improve the distinctness!

Comment: If you are aiming for distinctness, then I don't think that applying the *same* transfer function to all of the HRIRs will be of any benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Properly equalization improves the spectral accuracy of a binaural playback. It does not improve the spatial properties of the HRTFs other than that vertical localization is heavily dependent on proper spectral playback.

The best headphones for binaural playback tend to be diffuse field equalized and "acoustically open". This means that the headphone itself doesn't change the acoustic radiation impedance as seen from the ear canal into the outside world. It can actually be shown that headsets that are "acoustically open" do not require specific headphone equalization.

I'm not very optimistic about using Apple EarPods for this application. There is a huge amount of placement variability just through the way how deep and how hard you shove them into the ear canal. Small leaks between the pod and the walls of the ear canal make big changes in the frequency response and these vary greatly from person to person and even from placement to placement. So even if there was a set of functions published, it would not be a good fit for a specific person and placement.

Comment: That's super-useful!  I need proper over-the-ear headphones!

Comment: Whatever you get, make sure that they are open-back headphones. I have been very happy with these: http://amzn.com/B004444O46